# Python3 cross multiplication among tuples

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, data-science, python-module

I need to multiply the number in each tuple, not the order `i[0] * j[0]` and `i[1] * j[1]`, but `i[0] * i[0], i[0] * j[1], i[0] * j[2]` and so on.
Moreover, I need to add the number as well, such as `i[0] + i[0], i[0] + j[1], i[0] + j[2]` and so on.

Is there an easy way to do this, instead of my code below that needs a lot of for?

```
dice1 = (1, 2, 3, 4) 
dice2 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) 
dice3 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) 
dice4 = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12) 
dice5 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15) 
dice6 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20) 
 
myList = [] 
comp = [] 
d = 0 
e = 0 

for i in dice1: 
    for j in dice2: 
        d = i * j 
        myList.append(d) 
e = len(myList) 
comp.append(e)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can utilize the itertools product function as follows:

```
from itertools import product 
dice1 = (1, 2, 3, 4) 
dice2 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) 
dice3 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) 
dice4 = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12) 
dice5 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15) 
dice6 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20) 
 
myList = [] 
comp = []  
myList = [k[0] * k[1] for k in product(dice1, dice2)]
comp.append(len(myList)
```